# How to send webhook json payload to elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, webhooks, elastic-stack

My goal is whenever my webhook receives a POST request, I'd like to send that json payload to an ElasticSearch Index.

For this purpose, I used Logstash pipeline with HTTP plugin.
When I am using input from a webhook configured locally on port 9000, I am able to send webhook messages when my webhook is configured locally

```
input {
  http {
    host => "0.0.0.0"
    port => "9000"
    codec => "json"
  }
}
filter {
    mutate {
        add_field => {
          "documentType" => "productionlogs"
          "deleted" => "false"
          "created" => "%{@timestamp}"
          "modified" => "%{@timestamp}"
          }
    }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts    => [ '${ES_HOST_ADDRESS}' ]
    user     => '${ES_USER}'
    password => '${ES_PASSWORD}'
    ssl => "true"
    index => "production_logs"
  }
  stdout {
    id => "Pipeline_logs"
    codec => "json"
  }
}
```

but when I am using an external webhook endpoint from "https://requestinspector.com/" for example,

```
input {
  http {
    host => "requestinspector.com/inspect/xxxxx"
    port => "443"
    ssl ==> "true"
    codec => "json"
  }
}
filter {
...
```

```sh
No documents are added to elasticsearch index whi this error
[ERROR] 2022-03-02 08:21:07.004 [Converge PipelineAction::Create<pipeline-dev-webhook>] agent - Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:pipeline-dev-webhook, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of [ \\t\\r\\n], \"#\", \"=>\" at line 5, column 9 (byte 114) after input {\n  http {\n    host =>...
```

any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You simply wrote `==>` instead of `=>` at line 5 ;-)

```
    ssl ==> "true"
```

Should be :

```
    ssl => "true"
```

Errors beginning with `Expected one of ...` are usually typos / missing brackets / etc.

Comment: Thanks for the catch, now I'm having following error
```bash
[ERROR] 2022-03-02 17:21:24.094 [[pipeline-dev-webhook-signeasy]-pipeline-manager] javapipeline - Pipeline error {:pipeline_id=>"pipeline-dev-webhook-signeasy", :exception=>#<LogStash::ConfigurationError: Certificate or JKS must be configured>, :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-http-3.4.5-java/lib/logstash/inputs/http.rb:235:in `validate_ssl_settings!'", "..```
which related to SSL certificate I suppose

Comment: You have `ssl` configured in input, with host `requestinspector.com/inspect/xxx`. First: I think the host should be a domain, e.g. `requestinspector.com`. Then: that means the data sent to logstash is sent to `requestinspector.com/...` with SSL ; so you need to give logstash the requestinspector.com (private) certificate. If the webhook is external, e.g. on another server which then sends data to logstash : then setup `host` as `your-own-domain.com`, get a certificate and add the private cert to your logstash. (if your cert is autosigned, you might need to "trust" it in the webhook server)

Comment: Thanks, actually I am using it in a `K8s` cluster where I have one deployment for the `webhook` and another one for `logstash`, where pipeline is:
```input {
  http {
    host => $Webhook_POD_IP
    port => "9000"
    ssl => "false"
    codec => "json"
  }
...
```
it stills asks for ssl verification

```ERROR] 2022-03-09 11:00:12.871 [[pipeline-dev-webhook-signeasy]<http] javapipeline - A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.
  Pipeline_id:pipeline-dev-webhook-signeasy
  Plugin: <LogStash::Inputs::Http host=>"$$$$$$", codec=><LogStash::Codecs::JSON...```

Answer (score 1):

Hi @RedaE you can refer this blogpost:

https://ashish.one/blogs/elastic/receive-webhook-requests-using-elk/

`webhook-receiver.conf`

```bash
input {
  http {
    port => 9000
  }
}

filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
  }
}

output {   
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["https://es01:9200"]
    cacert => '/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/certs/ca.crt'
    user => 'elastic'
    password => 'pass@123'
    index => 'webhook'
  }
}
```